# How do I display a date with .toLocaleDateString() in a format like 29 Oct 2020 for en-us?

Tags: javascript, date, format

I'm not sure how to rearrange the order of the dates displayed from .toLocaleDateString().

```
thisDate.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { year: 'numeric', day: '2-digit', month: 'short', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true });
```

I've tried rearranging the option order, but nothing seems to rearrange the order so I get Oct 29, 2020 no matter what I do when I want it to display 29 Oct 2020 instead.

Comment: The formatting of *toLocale* methods is based on the language tag and options. If you want a particular format, then use trial and error with various language tags and options until you get the one you want, then hope that all implementations resolve them to the same format. Using "en-US" is unlikely to ever put the day before the month regardless of the options used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use a simple formatter to format your string:

```
string formattedDate = YourDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Here is more documentation on DateTime.ToString():
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: That isn't javascript (ECMAScript).

Comment: @RobG excuse me, you are totally correct. I thought this was c#.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `en-GB` locale

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', day: '2-digit', month: 'short' });

console.log(date)
```